# log4net logger configuration

Tags: configuration, logging, web-config, log4net

Is it possible to set the logger from configuration. I have a web app
using a framework. The framework is extensible and has the logger.
When I log, currently, the logger is set to the framework class.

Is it possible that I can configure my web app and set the logger for the web app to
`loggerForWebApp` and the logger for a console app (which is using the
same framework) to `loggerForConsoleApp`?

Comment: This is possible as I describe in my answer. But why would you share log4net configuration between these two apps? Could you isolate the console app from your web app and still be able to utilize your framework, or is it tied into the webapp?

Comment: Nope, I would not share it between 2 apps. I would want to pick it up at run time  from 2 different app/web.configs which would have different values.

Comment: Right. Why then do you need a webapp logger in the console app.config or a consoleapp logger in your web.config? Guess I'm not seeing the whole background for your question...

Comment: Hey Peter. I guess I did not phrase my question properly. I would have 2 applications using the same framework(and hence the same logging class).  The logger would be initialized like  private `static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logger"].ToString());`. In my web.config, I would have "appsettings" set to "webAPPLogger" and in my consoleApp, I would have "appSettings"  of "Logger" set to "ConsoleAppLogger". They can write to same/different database and now I would know which application is logging and what it is logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the root logger (which must always be there) you can have named loggers with their own appender-refs and levels.

For instance, you could have something like this:

```
<root>
....
</root>

<logger name="loggerForWebApp">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ... />
</logger>

<logger name="loggerForConsoleApp">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ... />
</logger>
```

In code, you would summon these loggers by their name:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("loggerForWebApp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely, and this is one of the great things about log4net: it can log out to a wide range of loggers.

For examples of the appenders, see [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html). Probably the most common one in use is the `RollingFileAppender`, but the `ConsoleAppender` can be very handy for console applications. Alternatively the `TraceAppender` can write out to the standard .NET trace listeners for further redirection (or display in the debug Output window in Visual Studio).

To create your own, implement [IAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/index.html).

*details to follow*

Comment: @Ram is not asking about appenders, he is asking about loggers. Two separate things in the log4net world.